# Java Graph Annotation properties pattern

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, properties, annotations

I have a Graph objects with nodes.
I need to have annotation objects which holds arbitrary properties for each node. In general, if one node has a property of type T, then all other nodes will have a property of that type.
Annotator object will then add properties to the annotation. This keeps my graph agnostic.
There is code to add a property of a certain type to a node, and code to retrieve a property by type.

Here is the code I currently have in my annotation class:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Property>, Map<Node, Property>> properties;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Property> T getProperty(Node node, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (properties.containsKey(clazz)) {
        return null;
    }
    return (T) properties.get(clazz).get(node);
}

public void addProperty(Node node, Property property) {
    if (!properties.containsKey(property.getClass())) {
        properties.put(property.getClass(), new HashMap<>());
    }

    properties.get(property.getClass()).put(node, property);
}
```

I believe this works fine, But the generics don't seem as strict as they could possibly be.
Is there a more elegant pattern I could be using?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the properties map is the best workaround you might have, given your current description.

Nevertheless, since you already have the `Class` instance you can use it to perform the cast to get rid of the warning (without the explicit `SuppressWarnings` annotation).

It would get something like this:

```
return clazz.cast(properties.get(clazz));
```

If you wanted an extra layer of protection against `NullPointerException`s you could change it into something like:

```
return clazz.cast(properties.getOrDefault(clazz, Collections.emptyMap()).get(node));
```

This would make your complete `getProperty` method something like:

```
public <T extends Property> T getProperty(Node node, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(properties.getOrDefault(clazz, Collections.emptyMap()).get(node));
}
```

Note that like an explicit cast using `Class.cast()` will throw a `ClassCastException` if the cast is not valid.

Also, don't forget to validate your arguments:

```
public <T extends Property> T getProperty(Node node, Class<T> clazz) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(node);
    Objects.requireNonNull(clazz); // Or inline them in the return, albeit not so readable
    return clazz.cast(properties.getOrDefault(clazz, Collections.emptyMap()).get(node));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill make those improvements!